# Adding a column of a categorical variables in sequence to a data frame list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have multiple data frames that I've read into one list. I want to add new column of a specific sequence of categorical variables to each data frame within this list.

For example, I have the following data frame list (data_list):

```
df1
             Slice    Count    
        1    C1       10          
        2    C2       2      
        3    C3       5    
df2
             Slice    Count    
        1    C1       3          
        2    C2       8      
        3    C3       6    
df3
             Slice    Count    
        1    C1       0          
        2    C2       0      
        3    C3       3
```

I wrote the following script:

```
region_name <- c("North","East","South")
data_list <- Map(cbind, data_list, Region = region_name)
```

This is what I get:

```
df1
             Slice    Count    Region    
        1    C1       10       North  
        2    C1       2        North
        3    C1       5        North
df2
             Slice    Count    Region    
        1    C1       3        East  
        2    C1       8        East
        3    C1       6        East
df3
             Slice    Count    Region    
        1    C1       0        South  
        2    C1       0        South
        3    C1       3        South
```

How can I get the Categorical variable to repeat in sequence within each data frame (not in sequence across data frames):

```
df1
             Slice    Count    Region    
        1    C1       10       North  
        2    C1       2        East
        3    C1       5        South
df2
             Slice    Count    Region    
        1    C1       3        North  
        2    C1       8        East
        3    C1       6        South
df3
             Slice    Count    Region    
        1    C1       0        North  
        2    C1       0        East
        3    C1       3        South
```

Comment: `data_list <- lapply(data_list, cbind, region_name)`

Comment: I found that converting the region_name variable to a data frame makes it work.

`df <- data.frame(region_names)`
`data_list <- Map(cbind, data_list, Region = df)`

Answer (score 0):

How about the following

```
# Generate some sample data
set.seed(2017);
lst <- lapply(1:3, function(i) data.frame(Slice = c("C1", "C2", "C3"), Count = sample(10, 3)))

# Add column Region for every data.frame in lst
region_name <- c("North","East","South")
lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) {x$Region = region_name; x});
lst;
#[[1]]
#  Slice Count Region
#1    C1    10  North
#2    C2     5   East
#3    C3     4  South
#
#[[2]]
#  Slice Count Region
#1    C1     3  North
#2    C2     7   East
#3    C3     9  South
#
#[[3]]
#  Slice Count Region
#1    C1     1  North
#2    C2     4   East
#3    C3     9  South
```

Answer (score 0):

Or we can use `map` with `mutate`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(data_list, ~ .x %>% 
                     mutate(Region = region_name))
```